# Shoreditch on WordPress with Clean URLs?

Tags: shoreditch

I know Shoreditch is not officially supported on WordPress, but I'm playing around with migrating from D7 to WP and Shoreditch looks pretty good in the admin pages of WP. When I use non-clean URLs for pages (like https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fview&reset=1&cid=1), it looks pretty good.

But when I want to use clean URLs (https://example.org/civicrm/contact/view/?reset=1&cid=1), WordPress reverts back to whatever theme I have activated. The data is there, so I know Clean URLs are working, but it's not using the theme I want.

Is there a way to get the Shoreditch plugin/theme to work with clean URLs? Or am I missing something to make it work?

Comment: I'd use one of the newer themes that is supported and maintained for WP.  https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions?filter=theme

Comment: Thank you, @Aidan. I'm looking through these; I don't see one that is very close to shoreditch, which we love. But I'll try them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Clean URL in a WordPress context is not the same as a Clean URL in a Drupal context. Drupal has no real concept of an "admin" area with its own theme, but this distinction is a fundamental part of WordPress.

The two URLs in your question demonstrate this distinction:

- The former is an "admin" URL - the page is rendered by the default WordPress admin styles and the CiviCRM content is rendered by Shoreditch.
- The Clean URL version is a "front end" URL - the page is therefore
  rendered with whatever front end theme you have activated and the CiviCRM content is rendered by Shoreditch if you have it set as your "Frontend Theme" in CiviCRM.

In summary, no you are not missing something. What you are seeing is expected behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, @christian-wach. Do you know of a good front end theme that looks very similar to Shoreditch? We love that style (tabs on the left, nice contact summary page). Some of our plugins (CiviCase by Compucore) require Shoreditch as well, so something close would be great.

Comment: There aren't really any front end themes for CiviCRM in WordPress as such because it is not expected that people will access CiviCRM admin content via the front end. CiviCRM front end content is stuff like Profiles, Event Info and Registrations, Contribution Pages etc.